# How to remove an old wood stove brick chimney?

Tags: chimney, masonry

I need to remove what is left of an old wood stove chimney that was partially removed from the top at roof level (one story) and the opening roofed over.

What is the best way to break out the bricks?

Comment: What's the question you want answered?

Answer (score 3):

A mid size rotary hammer (SDS plus or SDS max) with a point and a chisel will break the bricks out. Have an extra manual chisel, mason's hammer and prybar on hand (to free the rotary hammer, when you get carried away and plunge too deep).  Hand, eye and head (hard hat) protection are advised.  Dust masks, too.

[image][image][image][image]